# How do I use jQuery to display an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code here that is supposed change `display: none` to `display: block` on 1 element when you mouse over another element.

**HTML:**

`<li onmouseover="popup('Ipsum');">Lorem</li>`

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").append('<div id="pup"></div>'); // Appends a popup div to the page
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        var x,y;                                   // This sets the mouse
                                                   // coordinates into 2
        x = $(document).scrollLeft() + e.clientX;  // variables in order to
        y = $(document).scrollTop() + e.clientY;   // display the tooltip
    });                                            // relative to mouse postition

    function popup(text)
    {
        $('#pup').html(text);  // This is supposed to enter text into the tooltip
        $('#pup').show();      // div and change it from display: none to
                               // display: block
    }
```

Currently, the div exists (however you can't see it because it is set to `display: none` in the CSS, but when you mouse over the li it isn't displayed. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at moving the popup function's definition outside of the $(document).ready(...) block of code. It should be defined globally.

Comment: An alternative: you can simplify this tooltip idea a lot by just doing `<li title='Ipsum'>Lorem</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Russ C's comment. Move popup out of $(document).ready, but not as a global function. Assign it as an anonymous function and give jQuery as a parameter.

Didn't know you wanted help with the mouse events. This one appears below the mouse. The "title" attribute can only hold plain text, so if you want something not so robust, go with that.

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var loremHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href=''>Vivamus non elit risus</a>, a dignissim ligula."
        $("#lorem").hover(function() {$.popup(loremHTML)},function() {$("#pup").hide().remove()});
        $(document).mousemove(function(ev) {
            $.mousePos = {      //Assign mousePos to the jQuery object
                x: ev.pageX,    //x coordinate
                y: ev.pageY     //y coordinate
            };
        });
     });   

     (function($) {
        $.popup = $.fn.popup = function(text) {
            $("body").append('<div id="pup"></div>');
            $('#pup').show().css({
                "position":"absolute",
                "left":$.mousePos.x,
                "top":$.mousePos.y})
                .html(text);
        }
     })(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
        #pup {
            background:#ddd;
            padding:5px;
            width:20%;
        }
```

HTML

```
<span id="lorem">Lorem</span>
```

Comment: After having implemented this method into my Javascript, the popup now shows up whenever I mouse over the `li` element, which is exactly what I asked for in the question. Unfortunately, since the popup does not move along the page relative to my mouse, I think I will have to try to just resort to changing the element's `title`, even though I figured doing it like this would be an interesting experience. Thank you for your help, guys!

Comment: If you want #pup to move with the mouse, change your mousemove handler to update its position.